# Is this way system administration possible in the Android OS?

Tags: android

After reading the android device administration tutorial at vendor site, I have wondered that, Is it possible to disable hardware component of android device so that any application can not enable it ? Is this way system administration possible in the Android OS ?

Comment: What hardware component do you want to disable? And most importantly, why?? Put some thought while framing the question.

Comment: @SiddharthLele have you read the tutorial on the Android website about device administration ? The reason I am so big devil. I want to control the world via one application :)

Comment: Nice. Good luck with that. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele in this site there are some policies. I wonder if I disable one, in reality I want to know whether it is disabled and no application can enable or .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "hardware component", you really mean "camera", then yes, the device admin APIs can block access to the camera.

If by "hardware component", you really mean "any hardware component", then no, the device admin APIs do not allow you to block the screen, CPU, GPU, battery, keyboard (if present), sensors, etc.